# Byte Type in C#

Tags: c#

Hi 
Could you  explain me

Comment: Well, yeah sure !

Comment: Could you clarify what needs explaining?

Answer (score 5):

A `byte` is an unsigned 8-bit integer (literally consuming one byte of physical memory) that stores values in the range of 0 to 255. (See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693(v=VS.100).aspx).)

Answer (score 2):

Hi byte type in c sharp System.Byte, Range 0 to 255,    Size Unsigned 8-bit integer
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693(VS.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693%28VS.71%29.aspx)